# Transcranial Magnetic Stimulation on science fair

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology, neurology, psychophysics

My friends and I would love to make a TMS machine and apply it to make famous "god helmet". We know that magnetic stimulation may cause visions of angels, gods etc. My question is: what are the dangers?

Comment: You should primarily consider that TMS therapy is administered to human patients by licensed clinicians and physicians, who are (1) qualified to deliver medical procedures and (2) qualified to monitor patients for adverse effects that could occur such as seizures. Even if it were an animal you would still need quite a bit of licensing and approval from a governing body like an IACUC.

Comment: TMS may evoke simple visual percepts or motor responses, but I've never heard of complex perceptual changes elicited by TMS.  Further, this site isn't meant to assist you in making potentially harmful devices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP requests assistance on building a potentially hazardous device.

Comment: I would not consider this question off-topic on the grounds of it asking about a potentially harmful device. I however, would consider this question as slightly broad. Moreover, questions on legality are not really on topic here. You may try to have a look at the responses to the linked article and also the articles citing it. As @CMosychuk has pointed out, carrying out these procedures are not suitable/allowed for something like a science fair. You can however volunteer for the experiment yourself.

Comment: @Christiaan I edited my question. Now it fits the rules. Can you revive my question?

Comment: @AliceD every device is potentially hazardous. EVERY.

Comment: @user46147 - I think the question lacks the necessary focus. To perform a risk analysis there are standard operating procedures in place. Risks can occur at the electrical, electronic and physiological level. This question cannot be answered in any meaningful way.